# Detecting the Javascript Function which is called

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have an url which i am displaying in my iPad screen by using UIWebView. Now that page contains a bar chart, on selection of which a particular javascript function is getting called present in html file.

The webpage contains "N" number of javascript functions.

So how can i know that which function is getting called ?

I want to retrieve that function name in my native objective-c .

Comment: Is the JavaScript in question yours or something from the wilderness of the WWW?

Comment: wilderness of the WWW :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getItem(){
   var functionName =   arguments.callee.name;
   alert(functionName)  //outputs 'getItem'
}

getItem();
```

Comment: worth mentioning that `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` are both depricated and not available in ES5 strict mode.